# Can Cabinet Ministers initiate legislation, or does collective responsibility somehow preclude this?

Tags: united-kingdom, law

Can Cabinet Ministers initiate legislation, or does collective responsibility mean that technically the whole Government is the initiator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can Cabinet Ministers initiate legislation, or does collective responsibility mean that technically the whole Government is the initiator?

The latter. Members of the Government (which includes various grades of ministers and others, most of whom are **not** in the cabinet) are indeed bound by [collective responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_collective_responsibility):

> In the United Kingdom, the doctrine applies to all members of the government, from members of the cabinet down to Parliamentary Private Secretaries.

So yes, when a Government bill is introduced, it will typically list a number of members of the Government as its introducers or supporters. However, they are acting on behalf of the Government, not as individuals.

As a result of this principle, it would not be appropriate for a member of the Government to introduce a private members' bill. In fact, [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Members%27_Bills_in_the_Parliament_of_the_United_Kingdom) is quite explicit on this matter:

> A private members' bill (PMB) in the Parliament of the United Kingdom is a type of public bill that can be introduced by either members of the House of Commons or House of Lords who are not Ministers.